# Getting blank response from xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: xmlhttprequest

This is my code,

```
var url= "UpdateTeams.php?Disposition=" + Disposition + "&Subdisposition="+Subdisposition + "&Queue=" + Queue + "&Loans=" + Loans + "&ID=" +ID;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }

var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

When I change async to "false", I get response. But when I make it "true", I am getting blank responce. Kindly guide me here. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: That's what async does... By the time you are trying to retrieve the data the data has not been send back yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In async mode, you must the `onload` callback to get the returned content

```
xmlhttp.onload = function (e) {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
    if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
      var text = xmlhttp.responseText;
      alert(text);
    } else {
      console.error(xmlhttp.statusText);
    }
  }
};
```

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests for more details